# Android stock launcher, just without the Google Now search bar

Tags: android, open-source, launcher

The Nexus 5 comes with this useless and space-wasting Google Now search bar:

[image: Not Ok Google]

It is hard-coded, and I have been [told](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/120733/501) the solution is to modify the launcher's AOSP source code and remove the hard-coded bar. I guess someone has done it already, so that's the purpose of the present question.

Requirements:

- Just like the normal AOSP launcher, just without the bar and without Google Now.
- Widgets must be usable
- Open source, free
- Maintained to follow closely new upstream developments
- Available on Google Play or as an APK, or even better on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org)

Tried:

- [Mobiistar CM12 Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiistar.cmlauncher): Ads, no way to remove the search bar despite what description says
- [Splashshop Slim Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.slashshop.app.launcher): Not open source, not based on AOSP launcher, no widgets

*(NOTE: If you use LineageOS then just long-press the screen, choose Settings, then disable "Search bar")*

Comment: Google UIs are often good examples of wasted screen space.

Comment: Added answer to your original question on  Android enthusiasts

Comment: Any issues in using Cyanogenmod's Trebuchet or SlimROMS' Slim Launcher? I don't know how Google Now launcher looks but these launchers are close to stock with some cool features too. They also meet the rest of your three requirements.

Comment: @Firelord: Is Trebuchet usable only on Cyanogenmod? Is Slim Launcher really open source? Thanks!

Comment: @Firelord: Slim Launcher does not satisfy the first requirement. For instance, it does not support widgets

Comment: Slim Launcher is [open source](https://github.com/SlimRoms/packages_apps_SlimLauncher) (whole SlimROMS is open source actually). It does support widgets. I'm currently using this launcher is COS12 and it works well.I didn't try whether Trebuchet can be used in non-CM ROMs.

Comment: @Firelord: Are they available on Google Play or as APK? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.slashshop.app.launcher says "It shows no widgets", is it a different one?

Comment: @Firelord: Is the Slim Launcher you mentioned available as an APK somewhere for download, or on Google Play, or even better on F-Droid?

Comment: Sorry for commenting so late. In my case, I had the SlimROM installed as a secondary ROM on my non-Nexus device, so I simply grabbed the launcher's APK, copied it to my primary ROM and it worked. In your case, you can either build the APK yourself or grab the ROM and extract the APK yourself. May be, you can ask those developers to host the launcher somewhere, such as on F-Droid.

Comment: Checking [my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher#group_523), it seems like [Launcher+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.ndsc.kitkatlauncher) could be your candidate: *compiled straight from AOSP. Launcher+ focuses on clean and stable features […] Hide the Google Search Bar […] guaranteed to work on the Nexus 4 and 5* Description says nothing about the license, though – and it lists no homepage to cross-check with.

Comment: @Izzy: Please make that an answer, you deserve your bounty :-)

Comment: Thanks, @NicolasRaoul – done. Though it's not a "perfect match", it seems as close as we can get – and with no other answer present, we don't want to waste your bounty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking my [list of alternative launchers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher#group_523), it looks like **[Launcher+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.ndsc.kitkatlauncher)** should fit your needs. Quotes from its description answer your listed requirements:

- **Just like the normal AOSP launcher:** *compiled straight from AOSP*
- **just without the bar and without Google Now:** *Hide the Google Search Bar*
- **Nexus 5:** *guaranteed to work on the Nexus 4 and 5* (and yes, I know about the special issue with those devices concerning the search bar – so this is the master criterium)

Unfortunately, the description doesn't mention a license (and no homepage to check with), so I must pass on that requirement. At least it "ships at no charge", and is [available at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.ndsc.kitkatlauncher).

[image: Searchbar] [image: No searchbar, more space for icons]
<sup>Screenshots prove: Searchbar is there, but can be hidden (Source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.ndsc.kitkatlauncher); click to enlarge)</sup>

I have not used this app myself, so I cannot vouch for it from personal experience. Play store rating is 4 stars at almost 6k votes, so it cannot be that bad. And one of your criteria seems to be only met partly: *Maintained to follow closely new upstream developments* – there wasn't any update lately to this launcher. Still, if you want to get rid of the search bar on your N5, it should be a good choice.

---

Alternatives you might wish to take a look at (not mentioning all your requirements, but according to the screenshots and "reading between the lines" might be a close fit as well):

- **[Polaris Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.starnode.sysutils.polarislauncher.release):** More up-to-date. According to the screenshots, you can disable the search bar – which is explicitely mentioned (just found it): *Hide or move the position of individual desktop elements (search bar, dock, page indicator).* The N5 is *not* explicitely mentioned. Comes in a free version with in-app-payment to go Pro.
- **[Kcin Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kcinapp.launcher&rdid=com.kcinapp.launcher)** is based on AOSP, and a little more up-to-date. Doesn't mention search bar hiding, but screenshots *might* indicate that (the sentence *Highly customizable, with many useful settings* could mean anything ;) No license mentioned here either.

Comment: Too bad it is not open source... if there is any open source alternative feel free to give another answer :-)

Comment: I'm just cross-checking my resources, Nicolas, and will add some hints to my answer here – unless I find a "full match", which I then post in a separate answer :)